Movie about 4 friends and a bank robbery, 3 of them die in the end
A movie from the 80s or 90s. Starts in a small town, shows two guys meeting and getting ready to attend a friend's wedding, they pick up a tux from the dry cleaners. Pick up the 3rd friend, casually driving down one of them asks to stop at the bank to get some cash, as he enters he puts up a mask and starts to rob the bank. The friends outside in the car don't know anything about it, but soon learn that there is a robbery going on so they decide to do something about it only to discover it's their friend. Now the 4th friend whose wedding it is already in the bank, that makes all of them present there and involved in the mess.
There are cops outside now and there is no way out. The original friend explains he was doing it for his friend who was getting married so that he doesnt have to live a shit life like the one they have been living. Some senti but good direction. The people inside the bank are friendly as these guys are not very harsh on them. One of the hostages is a retired helicopter pilot or something and they chalk a plan with him.
They ask for a bus, and escape with some hostages. There is bus chase for a while then somehow they let the hostages free and the friend whose wedding it is gets airlifted by the helicopter guy along with the money. The rest of the friends confront the police blockade and die. Later they show the fourth friend on a beach with his wife free and happy.Any idea? i have been looking for this one since ages.

This is the plot of Best Men from 1997 with Luke Wilson, Drew Barrymore, Andy Dick and Dean Cain.

Jesse Reilly was released from prison and he is to be married to Hope. Shortly before the wedding, he is involved in a bank robbery with his friends Buzz Thomas, Teddy Pollack and Billy Phillips. It escalates to a hostage crisis, and the FBI is called. In an exchange of fire, a few men are shot. Hope and Jesse are then rescued by John G. Coleman in a helicopter.

Here's the trailer:




Walt, You are awesome ! The Best MAN ! :D
